# SQL - get all projects in which a person is inserted or not

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to have a query that gives me a list of all projects included in the database and, for a given person, if return is inserted or not this project.

So, i have the tables:

### Project

id (PK)

name

### ProjectPeople

id (PK)

idPeople

idProject

plafond

### People

id (PK)

name

and i use this query, but not works

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.ID as IDProject, 
    case when ProjP.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end as ExistProjP,
    ProjP.ID as ProjectPeopleID, ProjP.Plafond  
FROM Project P
LEFT JOIN ProjectPeople ProjP ON ProjP.idProject=P.ID
LEFT JOIN People PP on PP.ID = ProjP.idPeople
AND PP.ID = ISNULL(@IDPEOPLE,PP.ID);
```

anyone can help me?

Comment: How does it not work? Does it error (because you haven't declared @IDPEOPLE) or does it not return the rows you are expecting?

Comment: no, no... this query is inserted in a procedure ...

@IDPEOPLE is the variable

the query works but doesnt return what i want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know `@IDPEOPLE` you could following query:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, CASE WHEN pp.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS ExistProjP
FROM Project p
LEFT JOIN ProjectPeople pp ON (pp.idProject = p.id AND pp.idPeople = @IDPEOPLE)
```

This will return all projects along with a flag indicating whether the specified person belongs to the project.